# Seagate Dashboard 3 isn't showing latest backups

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive, restore, dashboard

I have a 3TB Backup Plus Desktop (Windows) and I'm trying to restore my files into a custom folder on a new computer (Windows 8.1).  The files were backed up on the drive from an older Windows 7 computer.

The last files backed up on the drive (all files, continuous) were dated 11 Nov 2014, but when restoring from Dashboard Agent 3 I can only see, and choose, backup versions through 31 July 2014.  August and beyond appear to not be accessible in DA3.  I see eight backup choices on the second step of the Restore wizard (two in January 2014, and one at the end of each month from Feb 2014 to July 2014) but the right arrow at the top of the window doesn't reveal any more backups.

So now I'm copying all of the files from August and beyond through Windows Explorer, which has many old versions that I don't need and take up a lot of space.

It looks like it restored fine through July, but I'd like it to restore from Nov 11th, of course.

Any insights?  Anyone run across this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a python script to do the restore.

I use the fact that alphabetical order for the incremental backup directories on the Seagate is chronological order.  The script steps through the directories from earliest to latest, and overwrites files in the destination directory, so the last version of a file written should be the latest file.

I had to move the whole backup to a very short first-level subdirectory on the Seagate because some of the paths ended up being more than 255 characters.  I also had to rename a few files that had unusual Unicode.

But ... here's what I used.  I used [this answer from SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15824216/13895) as part of the solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import shutil

def recursive_overwrite(src, dest, ignore=None):
    if os.path.isdir(src):
        if not os.path.isdir(dest):
            os.makedirs(dest)
        files = os.listdir(src)
        if ignore is not None:
            ignored = ignore(src, files)
        else:
            ignored = set()
        for f in files:
            if f not in ignored:
                recursive_overwrite(os.path.join(src, f), 
                                    os.path.join(dest, f), 
                                    ignore)
    else:
        shutil.copyfile(src, dest)

os.chdir('E:\\B')
dest = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\R4'
paths = os.walk('.').next()[1]

for path in paths:
    print path
    recursive_overwrite(path, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.   Upgrading to the latest version of Dashboard fixed it.